# Combining union and intersection types with brackets

Tags: typescript

If I have an interface:

```
declare interface APIResponse {
  type: string
}
```

And some payload:

```
declare interface Payload {
  prop: string
}
```

I also want the API response to be nullable, so I want to do this:

```
methodName: () => (APIResponse & Payload) | null
```

i.e. combining the response with intersection types, but also making the whole thing nullable. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the problem with `(APIResponse & Payload) | null` seems to work fine to me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it behaves exactly as you would expect:

```
interface APIResponse {
  type: string
}

interface Payload {
  prop: string
}

class Example {
    methodName(): (APIResponse & Payload) | null {
        // OK
        return { type: 'str', prop: 'str' };

        // OK
        return null;

        // NO! Missing 'type'
        return { prop: 'str' };

        // NO! Missing 'prop'
        return { type: 'str' };
    }
}
```

I have left multiple return statments in there as an illustration - obviously you can only have one :)